# Long text and photo in one row, reduce the picture

Tags: c#, html, css, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4 for me, I need to solve two problems.

1. Reduce the image, keep the proportions.
2. When I place a long text (40 characters) to the right of the picture - it moves under it

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top:110px;"  >
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div style="float:left">
            <img class="img-fluid z-depth-2 rounded" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image))" />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <h1 style="margin-left:300px" class="">@Model.Name</h1>
            <h5 style="margin-left:40px" class="">@Model.About</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top:110px;"  >
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div style="float:left">
        <img class="img-fluid z-depth-2 rounded" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image))" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <h1 style="margin-left:300px" class="">@Model.Name</h1>
        <h5 style="margin-left:40px" class="">@Model.About</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this

Possible solution can be:
using flex-wrap property setting it to nowrap
`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap`

Comment: I do not see what has changed

Comment: No it didn't help

Comment: Please add a explanation